# running an imf file using dosbox in parallel to a game

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

i am making a game for a school project in 16 bit 8086 assembly(with TASM and tlink) and wanted to add music to my game via playing an imf file, but tasm has trouble including the imf file.

so then i resorted to using imfplay.
it worked, however, when i tried running both my game and the music, when i click on the window running my game so i can play it, the music stops playing on the other window running imfplayer.
how can i run both programs in parallel, or better - solve the original problem?